# MySQL InnoDB, Autoincrement a secondary column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb

I have a table with books, there can be multiple copies of each book and I want to give each copy a copy number.

```
TABLE:
BOOK(book_pk, book_name, book_copy);
```

Basically each book_pk will be unique, but if there are two rows with the same book_name, one book_copy should be set to 1, and the other set to 2.

```
TABLE ROWS:
1, AAA, 1
2, BBB, 1
3, AAA, 2
4, CCC, 1
5, BBB, 2
```

So I want to auto-increment the primary key and keep track of the copyNumber as I insert new tuples of the same book_name.

Comment: MyISAM will do exactly what you want. The Innodb engine unfortunately does not have support for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO Book (book_name, book_copy) 
VALUES ( 
   'AAAA',
    (SELECT copy FROM ( SELECT IFNULL(MAX(book_copy),0)+1 as copy FROM Book) AS d)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The short version is that in MySQL it can't be done directly from the database.  Perhaps this is best described with two tables.  A `Book` table and a `BookCopy` table.  The `Book` table can have an auto increment just as you have.  The `BookCopy` table also has an auto increment but references back to the `Book` table.  This way you can have a Book for which you have no copies, and you can't have a `BookCopy` for an unindetified `Book`.

```
Book Table
Book(book_pk (auto increment), book_name, ...)

BookCopy Table
BookCopy(book_copy_pk (auto increment), book_pk (foreign key), ...)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The thing is I would like to keep the primary key of the BookCopy autoincremental. I already have a Book table as you suggested and a BookCopy table, which is the table in my OP.